# recibir json y enviar los parametros al modelo

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

tengo un json que estoy probando por postman

```
{

    "lead_id": 7,

    "status": 28,

    "update_status": "2020-07-20 14:16:49",
    
    "comentarios": "aaa",
    
    "contacto_valido": 2,
    
    "motivo_no_valido": "Datos incompletos / falsos"

}
```

el json si llega

```
    Array
(
[lead_id] => 7
[status] => 28
[update_status] => 2020-07-20 14:16:49
[comentarios] => aaa
[contacto_valido] => 2
[motivo_no_valido] => Datos incompletos / falsos
)
```

este array lo quiero pasar a un metodo para hacer una actualizacion

```
$CI->model_service->update_leads( $data["lead_id"], array('status' => $data["status"],
                        'update_status' => $data["update_status"],
                        'comentarios' => $data["comentarios"],
                        'contacto_valido' => $data["contacto_valido"],
                        'motivo_no_valido' => $data["motivo_no_valido"]) );
```

hay algunos datos que son string ¿por que no salen entre comillas?
deberian salir entre comillas
que puedo hacer?

Comment: La salida que estás mostrando parece ser un `print_r`, usa `var_dump` en su lugar para ver el tipo de dato de cada elemento.

Comment: ya salio gracias